# Postman Requests Receive a HTTP 401 Status Code

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, postman

I am working on creating a Node.js REST API, using the Express module, that redirects HTTP GET and PUT requests to another server. However, when running test queries in Postman, I always get HTTP 401 Unauthorized responses. Yet, when I try the same on query on the Chrome browser I get a successful response (HTTP 302). I read through some documentation on the HTTP request/response cycle and authorization. The server I am redirecting to uses HTTP Basic authentication. In my code I am redirecting the API call to my application server using the res.redirect(server) method. In my Postman request I am setting the username/password in Authorization tab for my request. I know this is gets encoded using base64, but I am guessing this isn't being passed on the redirect when done through Postman.

The following code snippets show what I've created thus far.

This is the Express route I created for GET requests

```
app.get('/companyrecords/:name', function(req, res) {

  var credentials = Buffer.from("username:password").toString('base64');
  console.log(req);
  var requestURL = helperFunctions.createURL(req);

  res.redirect(requestURL);
});
```

I define a function called createURL inside a file called helperFunctions. The purpose of this function is set up the URL to which requests will be directed to. Here is the code for that function.

```
module.exports.createURL = function (requestURL) {
  var pathname = requestURL._parsedUrl.pathname;
  var tablename = pathname.split("/")[1];
  var filter = `?&filter=name=\'${requestURL.params.hostname}\'`;

  var fullPath = BASE_URL + tablename.concat('/') + filter;

  console.log(fullPath);
  return fullPath;
}
```

Where BASE_URL is a constant defined in the following form:

http://hostname:port/path/to/resource/

Is this something I need to change in my code to support redirects through Postman or is there a setting in Postman that I need to change so that my queries can execute successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't tell Postman not to do what was arguably the correct thing.

Effectively clients *should* be removing authorisation headers on a redirect. This is to prevent a man-in-the-middle from sticking a 302 in and collecting all your usernames and passwords on their own server. However, as you've noticed, a lot of clients do not behave perfectly (and have since maintained this behaviour for legacy reasons).

As discussed [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3551) however you do have some options:

- Allow a secondary way of authorising using a query string: `res.redirect(302, 'http://appServer:5001/?auth=auth')` however this is not great because query strings are often logged without redacting
- Act as a proxy and pipe the authenticated request yourself: `http.request(authedRequest).on('response', (response) => response.pipe(res))`
- Respond with a 200 and the link for your client to then follow.

Comment: If I used the second method you specified, then I would not need to call Express' res.redirect method correct? I would instead be using the Node.js HTTP module to pipe the response back to the client.

Comment: Yes, so your server is handling the redirect for you. A fourth answer is to acknowledge that postman isn't good for testing this because browsers behave differently, and check the Location header in the response and re-make the request. Although that means that your API won't work with anything but browsers.

Comment: Oh really, is there any way to code an API that redirects to another server that would work with HTTP clients other than web browsers? If there isn't then I guess I'm wasting my time. I don't have much experience with coding APIs but I'm sure this isn't the first time someone's tried to build an API with HTTP request redirection.

Comment: To give you a clearer picture, I am trying to use Node.js to extend the functionality of my company's application. The application is an enterprise software system that has its own native API. However, since we've made a lot of customizations to the underlying database, I'm not sure the native API would support us querying and adding records to these custom tables. The only other solution I could think of would be to create a new API from scratch and this would totally suck.

Comment: Ok, so I kind of figured out what to do. Instead of trying to inject an HTTP authorization header into the existing req object passed into the Express route, I instead created a new request all together using the Node.js HTTP built-in module. I would then pass the options from the original req object to the new request. Below is a sample of the code I wrote to do this.

//Edit: Stack Overflow is limiting the characters in my posts.

Comment: Indeed- that's a very typical approach in api design- gathering data from various sources and then returning it. Although, note, if all you're literally doing is wrapping the request then piping it will make your more responsive and save memory compared to downloading the response and then forwarding it on.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that. Though now I ran into another issue. This is a sample of my code.

app.get('/companyrecords/:name', function(req, res) {

  const options = {
    hostname: 'myhost',
    ...
    auth: 'username:password'
    }
  }

  const myAppReq = http.request(options, (myAppRes) =>{
    console.log(`STATUS: ${myAppRes.statusCode}`);
    myAppRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
      res.send(chunk);
    });
  myAppRes.on('end', () => {
  res.end('No more data to send.');
    });
  });

  // myAppReq.write('');
  myAppReq.end();
});

Comment: OK- Well- can you ask that in another question? As you can see, comments are great for more detailed discussion / sharing new code.

Comment: Sure, I will definitely do that. Thanks for all your input and sharing your insights with me on this. I hope this helps others on the same quest as I. I've definitely learned a lot about APIs and the HTTP spec.